# Mysql [5.6] Innodb select query order by id asc limit 100 is much slower than desc

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, innodb, sql-delete

My table schema looks like this:

```
create table myTable (
   id int(11) not null auto_increment,
   name varchar(255) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=894609724 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Total number of the rows are not more than 500. Rows with `id < 894609000` are deleted. And does not exist in table**

When I do: `SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;` it response time is 50 ms.

But when I do: `SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100;` its response time is 10 sec. which is 200 times slower than the reverse order query.

Could anyone please tell me why this kind of behaviour?

**EDIT:** I did EXPLAIN {query} too, it gives the same result for both the queries.
[image: EXPLAIN {query} this result]

Comment: Can you show `EXPLAIN {query}` on both? Which MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack I have edited the question.

Comment: @Strawberry Modified it

Comment: But didn't answer either question.

Comment: @danblack replied to both of your questions

Comment: Is that the entire table (2 columns)?  Which version of MySQL?  Is it 10 seconds if you run the query again?

Answer (score 0):

Please do these 3 statements and provide the results:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'myTable';
OPTIMIZE TABLE myTable;
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'myTable';
```